# Не правильно работает цикл в php

Tags: php, файлы, for

```
for($i=0; $i<20; $i++){
    if($_FILES['img']['error'][$i]==0){
            $unical_id = time();
            $init_filename = $_FILES['img']['name'][$i];
            $file_extension = pathinfo($init_filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $filename = $unical_id.'.'.$file_extension;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][$i], "uploads/$filename");
            $new_photo = "uploads/$filename";
        //echo $init_filename;
    };
}
```

Comment: Почему он вставляет только последнюю фотографию??

Comment: потому что успевает это сделать в течение одной секунды? замените `time()` на `$i`  и проверьте сколько файлов получится.

Comment: А тогда же названия могут быть не уникальными, что делать?

Comment: я написал, проверьте, а не оставьте так. Если будут все файлы. значит весь цикл выполняется за секунду и проблема именно в этом.

Comment: Если у вас в принципе несколько пользователей могут файлы заливать, то и тут могут быть совпадения по времени.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо

```
$unical_id = time();
```

используйте

```
$unical_id = $i;
```

так как каждый переход циклом меняет значение `$i` - и таким образом вы получите разные `$unical_id`.

Comment: и что вы получите при следующей загрузке?